# How to add something like padding to an SVG group?

Tags: svg

I have the following SVG - which resizes nicely (and automatically) when my viewport (browser) resizes.

```
<svg x="0" y="0" width:"50%">
</svg>
```

What I would like is the contents to be `padding:5px` or something like that.

However, if I add a `<rect x="5" width="50%"/>` then it goes 10px further than it should.

What I want is `<rect x="5" width="50% -10px"/>` but this isn't valid.

Can anyone suggest a viable alternative?

Some that I've considered...

- 5px stroke - nearly works, except I need transparency, and the stroke renders on top of the fill
- Transform - but I've text inside as well, which I need to be crisp, so a transform will skew that...

Answer (score 1):

In svg2 this would become:

```css
rect {
    x: 5px;
    y: 5px;
    width: calc(50% - 10px);
    height: calc(50% - 10px);
}
svg {
    border: 1px dotted red;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<svg>
    <rect/>
</svg>
```

Or see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qcx18w22/).

Comment: OT: Erik, your site, referred to by SVG info page [examples link](http://dahlström.net/links/bookmarks.php/ed/svg), is severely broken.

Answer (score 0):

Surround the `<svg>` with a `<div>`. Make the div `width: 50%`, and add the padding to the div.  Then let the SVG fill the div (`width: 100%`).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}


.svgwrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="svgwrapper">
  
  <svg width="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 50">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="limegreen"/>
  </svg>
  
</div>
```

Is this what you were after?